# Проверка на вложенность

Tags: javascript

Вот функция обработчик события:

```
var plateBox = document.querySelector('.services_plate_box');
plateBox.addEventListener('click' ,function (event) {
    event.preventDefault;
    var elem = event.target;
    if(elem.classList.contains('services_plate'))
    {   
        if(elem.classList.contains('services_plate--show')) {
            rmClass(elem, 'services_plate--show');
            addClass(elem, 'services_plate--hidden')
            setTimeout(rmClass, 1000, elem, 'services_plate--hidden');
        }else{
            elem.classList.add('services_plate--show');
        }
    }else{
        return;
    }
},true);

function rmClass(elem, itemClass) {
        elem.classList.remove(itemClass);
    }
function addClass(elem, itemClass){
    elem.classList.add(itemClass);
}
```

она проверяет, если клик произошел на элементе с определенным классом, то выполняет действия.
Подскажите как добавить проверку, что event.target является потомком элемента с этим классом и применить действия к этому элементу ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо просто получить родительский элемент и сделать ту же проверку (или какую-то иную).

Получить родительский элемент можно при помощи функций `Node.parentElement()` или `Node.parentNode()`. То есть

```
var parent = event.target.parentElement();
```

Соответственно вы можете подниматься на уровень выше, если вас интересует не только непосредственный родитель, пока не найдете элемент или пока не выйдите на `null` и узел документа, смотря какой метод используете.

Подробнее о этих методах можно прочесть [на сайте MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)

Comment: @RusssCoder,Я смотрел в сторону методов contains и compareDocumentPosition.
А через parentElement нужно будет делать цикл......

Comment: @pepel_xD, Без этого никак